# Display more than 16 digits in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to set np.set_printoptions(precision=100) in python
but the output is still something like -0.00510610862213

Is there anyway to display e.g. 100 digits?

Comment: I don't think NumPy accepts any arbitrary precision

Comment: I hope you're aware that configuring the display precision won't do anything to give you more than 16 digits of precision for storage or computation.

Comment: ok. Thank you for letting me known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the display precision up to a point. For example, looking below
we can change the number of digits displayed up to a point after which no more
digits are displayed.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: np.random.seed(42)
In [3]: a = np.random.randn(1,1)
In [4]: a
Out[4]: array([[ 0.49671415]])

In [5]: np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
In [6]: a
Out[6]: array([[ 0.4967]])

In [7]: np.set_printoptions(precision=54)
In [8]: a
Out[8]: array([[ 0.4967141530112326730517224859795533120632171630859375]])

In [9]: np.set_printoptions(precision=55)
In [10]: a
Out[10]: array([[ 0.4967141530112326730517224859795533120632171630859375]])
```

**But**, it is unclear why you would want to do this since as @user2357112
eluded to, this will not change the numerical precision. The default in numpy is storing
64 bit floats, which as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), are only precise up to at most 15
significant digits

> This gives 15–17 significant decimal digits precision. If a decimal string with
>   at most 15 significant digits is converted to IEEE 754 double precision
>   representation and then converted back to a string with the same number of
>   significant digits, then the final string should match the original. If an IEEE
>   754 double precision is converted to a decimal string with at least 17
>   significant digits and then converted back to double, then the final number must
>   match the original.

An example of this is illustrated using

```
In [11]: np.float64('0.454125401')
Out[11]: 0.45412540099999998
```